# Laravel API pass multiple errors using ValidationException, but with customised status code/title

Tags: php, laravel, api, exception, laravel-5

I am currently using MessageBag and ValidationException class to return back an array of errors to my API users. The problem with this is that it always returns a 422, validation exception

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 422,
      "title": "Validation Exception",
      "field": "consignment.networkCode",
      "detail": "Service Denied"
    },
    {
      "status": 422,
      "title": "Validation Exception",
      "field": "consignment.networkCode2",
      "detail": "Service Denied"
    }
  ]
}
```

The use of message bag and this ValidationException provides an easy way to send back multiple API errors. But they are not necessarily validation errors. I looked at extending the class but could not figure out a way that I can customise the status and title for each message bag entry. Is this possible or is there a better way to respond API errors of this kind?

I am currently using this as follows:

```
$msg = new MessageBag();
foreach($response->error as $er){
      $msg->add($er->obj, $er->errorMessage);
}
$error = ValidationException::withMessages($msg->toArray());
throw $error;
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of how you're using the message bag and validation exception to send that response, because the resulting structure looks backwards.

Comment: @Bogdan I have added in my current implementation. Thanks